# iOS - Best way to get numbers out of NSString! (Geo coordinates)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, user-experience

For my internship I'm working on a App that uses GPS data! That's already implemented and I wrote a class which converts the double-value the mapView sends into an user-picked format for Geo Coordinates (Degrees, Degrees-Minutes or Degrees-Minutes-Seconds)! Now there are also text fields the user should enter some coordinates in for adding waypoints!

What's the best technique here to get a the seperate numbers out of a string in a format similar to this 57° 14' 03" N!
Since it's a user input, the format won't be this, it's only similar! So is it better to parse these out the string or maybe limit the users input method from a textfield to something more strict which only allows one format (separate textfields for each number f.ex.)!
Actually a question to UX rather than a how-to-do!

Answer (score 2):

Acting as the delegate of the text field and not allowing invalid content / format is a good first step.

For parsing the string, `NSScanner` is the appropriate class to use to split out the parts. If you tie the format down though, you could use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to separate each number by the space between them.

Answer (score 2):

First, a comment. Ending all your sentences with exclamation points is silly!

As to your question. Yes, you should enforce a strict input format on your users. If you look in the software developers's dictionary, user is a synonym for idiot.

I would suggest separate UITextFields for each numeric value of each lat/long, with the symbols drawn in place with labels. The user would enter degrees, and the input would jump to minutes. The user enters minutes, and the input jumps to seconds. The user enters seconds, and the input jumps to degrees on the longitude.

Validate each input as a well-formed number.

If you want to use free-form input of strings like "57° 14' 03" N!", you might want to create a regular expression to validate it, plus range-checking on the numeric parts. If you Google it you should find online docs on regular expression. I don't use them often enough to be able to write a regular expression off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I kinda got used to the !
I'll try my best

Comment: Not to be mean, but it makes you seem like an over-excited puppy.

Comment: Yes, I get that and as I said, I'll try my best. It's just that I somehow got used to end sentences with exclamation marks. Sorry for that